# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am stumped here. I have a processing page written in Server Side Javascript that builds an HTML table with some data from our system.

I call the page via the jQuery .load() function. The call works and the data is returned but something is happening that throws the error copies below. This also stops any calls that I am making after the .load().

You can see the page here

```
http://pages.email.tofw.com/page.aspx?QS=38dfbe491fab00eadb06a33c6c7834943533ebb484a35c6efcab45c78cd9df38#

I have tried .load(), .post(), .ajax()...
```

One note is that I notice when I alert the response it seems like our backend system is placing a few references to other js files. See below, that looks ok to me.

I should also mention,

that this happens in all browsers
the response is simply HTML (+ those js lines)
is well formatted
chrome reports the error in line 564 of jQuery which is some function called noop

Any helo is appreciated, I cannot spend another whole day trying to figure this out on my own.

Thanks in Advance

**JS added to response by our system**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pages.email.tofw.com/Script/HttpRequest.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pages.email.tofw.com/Script/pageTracking.js">               </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    absoluteBaseUrl = "http://pages.email.tofw.com/";
SaveAnalyticData(7000926, 'd7ba6684-ae81-48dd-bac7-969595eb9846', '92401e11-8737-4d03-a458-be89ca0cbecf'); 
</script>
```

**Error that Chrome is reporting**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.8.3.js:564
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.3.js:564
jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery-1.8.3.js:565
jQuery.ajaxSetup.converters.text script jquery-1.8.3.js:8258
ajaxConvert jquery-1.8.3.js:8143
done jquery-1.8.3.js:7779
callback jquery-1.8.3.js:8518
send jquery-1.8.3.js:8524
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.3.js:7986
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.3.js:6007
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.8.3.js:611
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.8.3.js:6004
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery-1.8.3.js:5777
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.3.js:5904
jQuery.extend.access jquery-1.8.3.js:814
jQuery.fn.extend.html jquery-1.8.3.js:5868
(anonymous function) jquery-1.8.3.js:7474
fire jquery-1.8.3.js:974
self.fireWith jquery-1.8.3.js:1084
done jquery-1.8.3.js:7803
callback
```

Comment: Not sure if that's your exact code, but your missing the closing bracket for your second `script` declaration for `pageTracking.js`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks or the input but I have found the issue. It turns out that one of the referenced js files was throwing an error which was showing an error page that contained full html document. So my response contained html tags which I guess upset jQuery

How I fixed it was to wrap my expected results in a div with a know name, then using the load function passed that div to give me only the contents of that div.

Worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are missing a **>** in the **2nd script tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
       src="http://pages.email.tofw.com/Script/pageTracking.js" > </script>
                                              Missing this ---- ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://pages.email.tofw.com/Script/pageTracking.js"            
</script>
```

Notice that you missed to close the script opening tag

This is your script reference fixed

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://pages.email.tofw.com/Script/pageTracking.js">            
</script>
```